# How to get telnet working in SCO openserver release 3.2v5.0.6?

Tags: networking, unix, telnet

I have a sco box (SCO openserver release 3.2v5.0.6) and I went and changed the ip address of the server via netconfig.

Sadly, telnet is no longer working when I attempt it from another computer to the sco box. Locally it telnets fine from the sco box. Running a ping to itself I get 0% packet loss. But, when I attempt to ping another computer on the network. I get:

> ping: sendto: Host is down

Would anyone know how I could overcome this?

I know telnet has big security issues but it is needed, and I would appreciate it thoroughly if anyone could me get the sco box operating on the network.

Update: attempt to diagnose:

Ping to self on 127.0.0.1 seems to be working fine

Ping to my laptop on the same network fails

No packets received.

Result of ifconfig -a

[ip config -a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcVDg.jpg)

Result of traceroute to router ip

```
1 * * *
2 * * *
3 * sendmsg: Host is down
```

Result of netstat -rn

[netstat -rn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn37L.jpg)

Background:

Whats caused this is that an extra router has been added, in that the bt hub has been made to bridge to an apple hub which is using a pppoe connection to the internet. The sco box instead of being directly plugged into the apple hub, it is plugged into another netgear router which is then plugged into the bt hub. Maybe it is taking the sco box as being on a different network.

Comment: Please provide more information. Your problem can't be diagnosed without some basic details about your network, server config, other machine config, etc... `ifconfig -a`  output.

Comment: Ryan babchisin I shall update the question with further information in morning.

Comment: I would love to hear the business reason behind needing telnet. Using it these days, even on a trusted network is borderline professional irresponsiblity.

Comment: This thing is truly ancient, and from a little poking around on the net, it appears that SCO made it rather difficult to install ssh. This box should have been put out to pasture years ago.

Comment: Any suggestions why it won't work? Pomg failure suggests network issue ?

Comment: Check your firewall rules.

Comment: EEAA I believe that the SCO openserver release 5 doesn't have a firewall.

Comment: SCO, hubs, and an Apple Time Capsule. BINGO!

Comment: mfinni indeed. Got there in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it: it was an issue with the configuration. I removed the sco box from the switch and swapped it with the mail server to be directly plugged in the router; and the mail server is now plugged into the time capsule.